# limit image movement inside canvas

Tags: c#, windows-8

In windows 8 application, I am dragging an image inside a canvas. I want to bound that image inside canvas. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

### XAML

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="White" > 

     <Image x:Name="image1" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta_1" ManipulationMode="All">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image></Canvas>`
```

### C#

```
private void Image_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var imag = (CompositeTransform)image1.RenderTransform;
        imag.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        imag.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code:

```
CompositeTransform imgTrans = image1.TransformToVisual(canvas1);
   Windows.Foundation.Point imgPoint = imgTrans.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point());
 var imag  = (CompositeTransform)image1.RenderTransform;

    if (imgPoint.X <= 0)
    {
       imag .TranslateX -= imgPoint.X + 5;
       imag .TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }
```